# recorrer un ciclo for para una tabla con checkbox

Tags: php

tengo un formulario con una tabla , dicho formulario lo uso para realizar pedidos de material los datos del pedido se almacenan en la base de datos , al recuperar los datos de la base en otra pagina diferente de donde llene el formulario visualizo el pedido que se realizo al ver los materiales que pidieron salen materiales repetidos y aparecen materiales que no seleccionaron.

en este primer codigo es donde mando mis materiales por medio del checkbox.

```
<?php
$m_result=mysql_query("select id, material from material");
?>
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
?>
<table class='mat' border='1'>
<tr><td>MATERIAL</td><td>Seleccione</td></tr>
<?php
while ($mat=mysql_fetch_object($m_result)) {
    ?>
<tr><td><?=$mat->material?></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='mat<?=$mat->id?>'></td></tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

en este segundo codigo recorro mi tabla de materiales con un ciclo for que es donde creo esta el problema , aqui pienso que es donde se me generan materiales que no seleccione.

```
$q=mysql_query("insert into pedido (idpedido, fecha, hora, cliente, solicito,  vendedor, comventas, estado, importemn, importedls, tipo, contacto, telefono, prioridad) values ('$pedido','$fecha','$hora','$cliente','$solicito','$vendedor','$comventas','$estado', '$st', '$sts', '$v','$cont', '$tel', '$prioridad')");

if($q)
{
    //$i=1;
    for ($i=1; $i<=24; $i++) {
    $material=$_POST['mat'.$i];
    if($material!=''){
    $m=mysql_query("insert into pedmat (idpedido, idmaterial, material) values ('$pedido', '$i', '$material')");
    }
}
}
if ($q)
{
?>
```

y en este tercer código es donde genero mi tabla en otra pagina independiente del formulario para ver los pedidos realizados y ver que materiales pidieron.

```
<table border='1' class='listo'>
    <tr><td>ID</td><td>Material</td><td>Listo</td></tr>
<?php
$q=mysql_query("SELECT idmaterial, flisto from pedmat where idpedido='$id' and flisto='0000-00-00'");
while ($q1=mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
    $p=mysql_query("select material from material where id='$q1[0]'");
    while ($p1=mysql_fetch_array($p))
     {
        ?>
        <tr><td><?php echo $q1[0];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $p1[0];?></td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' name='<?php echo "idmat".$q1[0];?>' value='<?php echo $q1[0];?>'></td>
        <?php
     }
}
}//if

?>
```

aqui llene mi formulario y seleccione el material
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en esta segunda imagen es cuando recupero los datos enviados y almacenados en la BD para mostrarlos en una nueva tabla solo que me aparecen materiales que yo no seleccione en mi primer formulario y tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En el `INSERT` estás agregando de forma arbitraria 24 artículos: `for ($i=1; $i<=24; $i++) {` La mejor manera de resolver tu problema sería combinando tu código con Javascript/Ajax. Desde Javascript, cuando se pulse el botón de Enviar Pedido, recorres toda la tabla, seleccionando los elementos que hayan sido chequeados y demás datos que necesites como precio, cantidad, etc... metes todo eso dentro de un objeto y lo mandas al servidor vía Ajax para que sean insertados en la base de datos. Si aprendes a usar Ajax verás lo fácil que es hacer este tipo de cosas. Además, sin recargar la página.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te recomiendo almacenar los materiales seleccionados en un array, eso lo haces colocando [] al final del atributo name del checkbox.

Cambia esto:

```
input type="checkbox" name="mat[]" value="<?=$mat->id?>"
```

Luego recupera estos datos en tu archivo receptor del formulario (controlador)
y puedes hacer un `var_dump(mat)`, con lo cual sabrás si los datos corresponden.

después te queda recorrer el arreglo y almacenar en la base de datos.

```
 $cont = count($mat); 

 for ($i= 0; $i< $cont; $i++){

 $m=mysql_query("insert into pedmat (idpedido, idmaterial, material)
 values ('$pedido', '$mat[$i]', '$material')"); 

 }
```

suerte y como consejo, te recomiendo el uso de framework que ayudan mucho en el desarrollo y facilitar trabajo.

Comment: ok perfecto, solo que no me quedo muy claro esta parte: Luego recupera estos datos en tu archivo receptor del formulario (controlador) y puedes hacer un var_dump(mat), con lo cual sabrás si los datos corresponden.

después te queda recorrer el arreglo y almacenar en la base de datos.

Comment: var_dump es una función de php el cual te muestra todos los datos de un arreglo por pantalla.
tienes un formulario, los datos de este formulario viajan a otro archivo php mediante el action, es decir, debes tener un archivo php que recibe la información del formulario.